Is “every cat is identical to some mammal” logically equivalent to “every non-mammal is identical to some non-cat”?

a stands for every
e stands for some
n stands for negation
R stands for relation
Addition stands for disjunction
Multiplication stands for conjunction
C stands for cat
R stands for is identical to
M stands for mammal
aCReM or every cat is identical to some mammal.
anMRenC or every non-mammal is identical to some non-cat.
Thus, Is aCReM logically equivalent to anMRenC?


In pure mathematical logic X implying Y would mean that not Y implies not X. If all cats are mammals, then a non-mammal cannot be a cat.     But your use of "identical to" is confusing; I don't know how you are defining that term.

“every cat is identical to some mammal” means simply "Every Cat is a Mammal".

@MauroALLEGRANZA: thanks for the clarification. Equality, identity, and set membership are not always interchangable. You might want to edit the question to use a more standard term. (Is this a translation problem?)

Not necessary... as per answer below, the formalization of your convoluted expression boils down to the standard one.

From Conifold:

You mean ∀x(C(x) → ∃y(M(y) ∧ x=y)) and ∀y(¬M(y) → ∃x(¬C(x) ∧ x=y))? Yes, they are classically equivalent. By substitutivity of identity, y can be replaced by x in the first formula and x by y in the second. The ∃ quantifier and = then become redundant and they reduce to ∀x(C(x) → M(x)) and ∀y(¬M(y) → ¬C(y)), respectively, i.e. contrapositives of each other.

